# Displaying data from SQLite database incrementally

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, display

I want to be able to display values from my SQL database five at a time and then on button click be able to display the next five until I have display all of the courses. Right now this is how I am trying to display them:

```
 <%= form_for(Stc.new, action:'stcs#create') do |form| %>

 <%= collection_check_boxes(:course_id, Course.all, :id, :title,{}) do 
 |form| %>


 form.label { form.check_box }


 <% end %>
 <%= form.collection_select(:course_id, Course.all,:id, :title, {}, { 
 :multiple => false}) %>


 <%= form.select(:semester, options_for_select([['Fall', 'Fall'], 
 ['Spring', 'Spring'],['Summer', 'Summer']]), :id => 'sel1') %>


 <%= form.select(:year, options_for_select([['2012', '2012'], ['2013', 
'2013'], ['2014', '2014'], ['2015', '2015'], ['2016', '2016'], ['2017', 
'2017']]), :id => 'sel2') %>


<%= form.select(:user_id, options_for_select([[1,@user.id]])) %>
<div class="actions">


 <form id="my_sample_form">

</form>


  <input type="submit" value="Submit" form="my_sample_form">


   <% end %>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do pagination here you can use a gem for that,
one gem is 'will_paginate' gem.

read about that https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Comment: I added the <%= will_paginate @posts %> line to my view and added a controller and it's not working

Comment: In Controller @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30) do these

Answer (score 1):

You can try Kaminari gem for pagination.Refer this:

https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari

Comment: I added the <%= will_paginate @posts %> line to my view and added a controller and it's not working

Comment: have you set the per page limit  as Cource.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)